# Equivalent command for $USER IN windows command line

Tags: linux, windows, docker

Sorry for a very basic question.  I have to run the following command in a windows docker environment. The below is taken from Linux tutorial. However I want to run the same in Windows.  What is the equivalent of $USER in windows? Where should i look for?

```
docker build --pull -t $USER/tensorflow-serving-devel -f Dockerfile.devel .
```

I just tried without the $USER in windows "cmd" as below:

```
docker build --pull -t tensorflow-serving-devel -f Dockerfile.devel .
```

But I am getting an error as The system cannot find the specified path.

Please help

Comment: The equivalent of `USER` in Windows is `USERNAME`, which in CMD needs to be wrapped in percent characters, e.g. `%USERNAME%`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re looking for `%HOMEPATH%`. Like this:

```
docker build --pull -t %HOMEPATH%/tensorflow-serving-devel -f Dockerfile.devel .
```

Comment: Thankyou. Will check and accept the answer once i am in office